# Git for Windows

Tags: windows, git

I am a new user of Git for Windows.  I have installed from Google Code (1.8.1.2, and 1.7 as a trial).

I can issue some git commands, and they are fine and work perfectly.  However, the 'git diff' and 'git log' commands do not work.  These commands both come back with

```
'': : command not found
```

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing.  I also have GitHub for Windows on my machine.  The machine is Windows 7, very new build.

Could anyone help or give me diagnostic pointers as to why these two commands fail?

Comment: What do `GIT_TRACE=1 git diff` and `GIT_TRACE=1 git log` return?

Comment: trace: built-in: git 'diff'
        trace: run_command: ''\'''\'''
        '': : command not found      

.  Same thing for git log also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .gitconfig, the pager value was an empty string.  Any git command that pipes to a pager (ie git-diff or git-log) will fail with a command-not-found because DOS is being asked to run an empty string as a command.  No idea how it happened.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your .gitconfig file might not be setup correctly, or the environmental PATH is missing.

For folks that are new to git I almost always recommend that they first start with either

[Git Hub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/)  (easiest for new folks)

or

[Git Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/)  (not sure if this is what you installed)

Comment: .gitconfig is...  [user]

 name = Steve Hibbert
 email = stevehibbert@email.com
[core]
 editor = subl
 pager = ''
[gui]
 recentrepo = C:/Home/Rialto

Comment: Path too big to paste, but other git commands work, so I know that git.exe is at least being found, so I assume the git executable directory is in the PATH system environment var.

Comment: It was the .gitconfig - just a blank pager.  Thanks for your efforts, much appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

> Path too big to paste

Make sure your PATH is not *too big* or it might end up truncated, with strange side-effects (like, potentially, your error messages)

Try and launch [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat), or the [`git-bash` shortcut](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/share/WinGit/Git%20Bash.vbs), both included in the [msysgit distribution](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit).
They will complement the PATH and set `HOME` (which is very important, since Windows doesn't set `HOME` by default)

In those sessions (`git-cmd` or `bash`), `git diff` should work.

The actual solution was like the one in "[msysGit: Why does git log output blank lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899187/msysgit-why-does-git-log-output-blank-lines/2899403#2899403)": **set the pager**

```
[core] 
   pager = less -R
```

Comment: Yes, a huge PATH variable would be a problem.  I have tested the PATH, by putting a simple batch file in the last named directory (happens to be a JRE7 directory) and calling it from outside that directory - and it's good, so it's not the PATH variable truncating, but good idea.

Comment: ...and yep, I am using Git Bash, I should have included that in original notes.

Comment: @SteveHibbert since you have several Git installed, is there any chance that msysgit tries commands with the wrong git (the one from TortoiseGit or "GitHub for Windows")? Could you try and set a *minimal* path (like `C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\prog\git\PortableGit-1.8.0-preview20121022\bin`) in a `git-cmd.bat` session, and see if that works better?

Comment: Edited the git-cmd.bat file to a the above minimal path, plus the local location of the git files - same error.  I am not sure it's the PATH variable, because some git commands work, and some (log and diff that I have found) do not.  Thanks for the test suggestion though.

Comment: @SteveHibbert is there any git alias (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7066424/6309) which could explain that `diff` and `log` doesn't behave properly?

Comment: Nope, the .gitconfig is minimalist.  It is included in a comment in the section below, the reply from Chadit.

Comment: @SteveHibbert don't forget you have 3 config files. check what `git config -l` returns.

Comment: Just thought, looking at my gitconfig file, the pager is blank.  If the log and diff options use a pager it could be that.  What should the pager be on Windows?  More?  Less?

Comment: Speculatively have set pager to less. This works! The .gitconfig file looks like this...  [user]

        name = Steve Hibbert
        email = stevehibbert@home.com
[core]
        editor = subl
        pager = less
[gui]
        recentrepo = C:/Home/Rialto

Comment: @SteveHibbert I would say `less -R`, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2899403/6309

Comment: Indeed.  Thanks for trying to help, it is very much appreciated.  I need git for work so without some key commands, life was a bit tricky.

Comment: @SteveHibbert Excellent. I have included that in my answer for more visibility.