# Garbled text in msysgit on scrolling

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

If execute some command which will show plenty of text, the text will be disorder after scroll pages, is there any way to avoid that?

I don't want cygwin solution, the color in git bash is more comfortable to use, tools like gitk is awesome as well, if there is no solution, what is the best environment to use git command by command gui on Windows base OS.

[image: git bash]
<sub>(source: [i.imm.io](http://i.imm.io/1juR8.png))</sub>

Comment: This is so friggin annoying and happens on every machine I've tried on.. why aren't more people complaining about this? :/

Comment: @SalmanPK Never seen it.  Have you reported this bug?  https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit

Comment: @EdwardThomson Done: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/257

Answer (score 0):

It might be a pager issue, as I [mentioned in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2899403/6309):

Try a:

```
git --no-pager diff --color=always HEAD~1 -- yourFile | less -R
```

Comment: @吳承諺 are you using a DOS session, or a git-bash windows (http://i.stack.imgur.com/a6O8c.png)?

Comment: @吳承諺 Try git-cmd session. Calls `git-cmd` in your DOS session.

Comment: How? nothing happened when typing git-cmd in DOS session.

Comment: @吳承諺 look at the root directory of your git installation: there is a `git-cmd.bat` there.